# How do I remove certain tags and contents with PHP, using PHPCrawler

Tags: php, dom, phpcrawl

I am currently using PHPCrawler for some search functionality on a site. I need to remove some of the page elements from being indexed.

For example, I have used:

```
$doc_body = preg_replace('/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/is', "", $doc_body);
```

to remove lists, because I don't want the lists in the results. This works exactly as it should.

Now, another thing I need to remove is the following:

```
<div class="example">all contents within</div>
```

so for this I have tried:

```
   $doc_body = preg_replace('/<div(.*?)class="(.*?)example(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/div>/is', "", $doc_body);
```

Which produces an error because perhaps not every page has the div class example.
So I have adapted it with the following code:

```
      if(strpos($doc_body,'<div class="example">')){
      $doc_body = preg_replace('/<div(.*?)class="(.*?)example(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/div>/is', "", $doc_body);
      }
```

That unfortunately does not work either! It doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't remove  and all contents from the results.

This is my first time working with either phpcrawler or Domdocument...although I am not sure if my problem here has anything to do with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) and [XPath](http://php.net/domxpath) which is used to query the document model much like CSS does, but with a bit different syntax. W3Schools have a lightweight tutorial on XPath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

Regular expressions is always a bad idea when parsing an entire document since it is both resource heavy and time consuming.

E.g, to find every div with the class "example" using `XPath`, you'd just query the document as such;

```
//div[@class="example"]
```

Then remove the nodes with the `DOMDocument` api and finally normalize, in order to get the final result.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Remove all the lists
foreach ($xpath->query("//ul | //ol") as $node) {
     $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

// Remove all <div class="example" /> nodes
foreach ($xpath->query("//div[@class='example']") as $node) {
     $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$doc->normalize();

// Get the final document for indexing
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Great answer...thanks for pointing me in the right direction. the following happend to be the specific solution to my issue, but familiarizing myself with xpath was the way to go: `foreach ($xpath->query("//div[@class='example']") as $node){  
     $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);`

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. Been a while since I implemented DOMDocument. I've updated my answer.